# Price does not show up fully for a product

Tags: display, price

I got this problem on a website. The price does not show up fully on the site although, we entered the price in seven figures. Could anyone please guide me how to fix this issue?

The website at hand is showing 300 yen for the price of a unit. But the actual price added was was 3 million instead of just 300 yen. 
May I know how to solve that problem.

Thanks

Comment: but rest of products are showing proper price

Comment: You are rigjht. The other products are showing  price without any problem. Do you have any idea how to fix this issue?